# Regular expression excluding subpattern in mysql.log

Tags: mysql, regex

I am looking for recovering from my local mysql.log file the changes to perform to the production server and I already got the changes using:

```
^.*(ALTER TABLE).*(ADD|DROP|CHANGE|^AUTO_INCREMENT).*$
```

.. and I would also catch the `CREATE TABLE` statement excluding `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. So I tried to firstly only avoid the `SHOW` but I am not succeding using the more intuitive ways in my mind:

```
^.*(^SHOW)*(CREATE TABLE).*$

^.*(^SHOW CREATE TABLE|CREATE TABLE).*$
```

Any help is appreciated,

Carmine Iaciofano

Comment: Look into negative lookbehind assertions, if supported by what I assume is egrep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems negative look aheads and behinds could be used to solve your problem. The following regex should do the job in this case.

```
(?<!SHOW )(CREATE TABLE)(?! IF)
```

In this case, it finds any instances of "CREATE TABLE" that is not preceded by "SHOW " or followed by " IF". Note the spaces in the groups.

You can then use

```
^.*(?<!SHOW )(CREATE TABLE)(?! IF).*
```

to match the whole line.

You can read up on look aheads and look behinds [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: .. great! It works. I tried negative lookaheads in many ways but I missed the space after "SHOW". I will care of the link you attached and will study. Thanks!